# Problem about Riemann integrable function's uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I have no idea of how to answer the following question. It seems that the function is recurrence.[image]

Comment: Since $F_0$ is bounded, say by $M,$ it is $-Mx\le \int_0^x F_0(x)dx\le Mx.$ Repeat the argument.

Comment: But how can I extend to Fn(x)

Comment: Since $-Mx\le F_1(x)\le Mx$ it is $-\frac{M}{2}x^2\le F_2(x)=\int_0^x F_1(x) dx\le \frac{M}{2}x^2.$ By induction, $-\frac{M}{n!}x^n\le F_{n+1}(x)=\int_0^x F_n(x) dx\le \frac{M}{n!}x^n.$

Comment: Remember that $ x \in [0,1]$ and use Weierstrass M-test